# Obtener atributos documento XML

Tags: php, xml

He intentado obtener los elementos de la etiqueta `<facts>` cuando entra al ciclo no me muestra ninguna salida, ya intente con los métodos `children()` y `attributes()`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Facts away_team_id="368" away_team_name="France" competition="European Championship Finals" competition_id="3" game_date="2016-07-10 20:00:00" game_id="838557" home_team_id="359" home_team_name="Portugal" lang_id="es" last_modified="2016-07-07 22:02:42" matchday="7" season="Season 2015/2016" season_id="2015" sport_id="1" sport_name="Football" state="pre">
    <message id="1" fact="Este ser&amp;aacute; el cuarto encuentro entre Portugal y Francia en un gran torneo. Los franceses han ganado los tres anteriores, todos en semifinales (EURO 1984 EURO 2000, Copa Mundial 2006). " />
```

Comment: Podes aclarar en tu pregunta, como fue que lo intentaste? mira por favor [ask] y [mcve]

Comment: El XML debe estar bien formado

Answer (score 0):

OJO: Tu XML tiene serios problemas de validacion y estructura, te recomiendo cheques una referencia antes como la siguiente: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/

Puedes hacerlo por medio del índice del atributo:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("tuarchivo.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->Facts[0]['away_team_id'] . "<br>";
echo $xml->Facts[0]->title['away_team_name'];
```

Producira la salida:

```
368
France
```

Para hacerlo con un for:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("tuarchivo.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $facts) { 
    echo $facts['away_team_id'];
    echo "<br>"; 
}
```